# fullpage.js How do I control the scrolling speed when jumping from one section to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js with a lot of sections and anchor links, and from what I see the scrolling speed is the same wether the anchored section is just the next one or say 3 or 5 sections after.

So for example if I want to go from the top to the last section of the page with an anchor link, all the sections in between will show and scroll at the speed of light before I reach the last one, which is kinda problematic.

How can I change this speed depending on the distance between two sections?

Comment: What's the end goal? Are you trying to reduce the speed when it's moving past several sections?

Comment: @Narong The opposite, actually. I'd like to keep the default (700) speed when it's moving one section down or up, but to have it scroll smoothly when it moves past several, depending on wether they're very far or not. Like a basic smooth scroll script actually. I hope it's more understandable?

Comment: What you're saying is the default scroll speed of 700 is fine for you, when it's moving up or down 1 section, but it's too fast when it's moving past several sections, correct? So to make it appear to be scrolling smoothly, you'd want to slow down the scroll speed, correct? You don't want to increase it. Edit: I understand what you mean. You want to increase the scrollSpeed value, which slows down the scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used this, but according to their [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs), I believe it can be done using the `onLeave` event:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
    var idx = Math.abs(index - nextIndex)*.1;
    $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(idx*700);
    }
})
```

You can change the "intensity" by adjusting the `.1`.